# Spread Designer 6.0 visual basic 6.0 check box selected by default

Tags: vba, vb6

I'm new to VB6 (I Know... it's very old but its what we still use)

I'm having an issue with one of the old grids I have to make changes to. As you can see in the image below this grid is designed in the Spread Designer and what I need to do is simply have the "Change" columns selected by default when the form loads up.
I have searched here where I can change the properties for this column and the only thing I have found so far is the Cell Type pop-up when I right-click and click on edit.

Anyone can point me in the correct direction here?

[image: Spread Designer 6.0 visual basic]

I believe this is where I might have to make any changes.

```
Private Sub GrdPriceChanges_LeaveCell(ByVal Col As Long, ByVal Row As Long, ByVal NewCol As Long, ByVal NewRow As Long, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim VatRate As Variant
Dim CostPrice As Variant
Dim SellPrice As Variant
Dim vData As Variant
Dim Margin As Variant

    If Col = 9 Then
        GrdPriceChanges.Row = Row
        GrdPriceChanges.Col = 9
        If CellPrice <> GrdPriceChanges.Value And CellPrice <> 0 Then
            GrdPriceChanges.Col = 11
            GrdPriceChanges.Value = 1
            
            GrdPriceChanges.GetText 12, Row, VatRate
            GrdPriceChanges.GetText 9, Row, SellPrice
            GrdPriceChanges.GetText 8, Row, CostPrice
            GrdPriceChanges.Col = 10
            GrdPriceChanges.Value = CalculateMargin(Val(VatRate), Val(CostPrice), Val(SellPrice))
        End If
        
    ElseIf Col = 10 Then
        GrdPriceChanges.Row = Row
        GrdPriceChanges.Col = 10
        If CellMargin <> GrdPriceChanges.Value And Val(CellMargin) <> 0 Then
            Margin = GrdPriceChanges.Value
            GrdPriceChanges.Col = 11
            GrdPriceChanges.Value = 1
            
            GrdPriceChanges.GetText 12, Row, VatRate
            GrdPriceChanges.GetText 9, Row, SellPrice
            GrdPriceChanges.GetText 8, Row, CostPrice
            GrdPriceChanges.Col = 9
            GrdPriceChanges.Value = SuggestPrice(Val(CostPrice), Val(Margin), Val(VatRate))
        End If
    End If

    GrdPriceChanges.Col = 9
    GrdPriceChanges.Row = NewRow
    CellPrice = Val(GrdPriceChanges.Value)
    GrdPriceChanges.Col = 10
    GrdPriceChanges.Row = NewRow
    CellMargin = GrdPriceChanges.Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select a **cell** upon loading the form:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
   GrdPriceChanges.SetActiveCell 10, 1
End Sub
```

To select a **column** upon loading the form:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
   GrdPriceChanges.SetSelection 10, 0, 10, GrdPriceChanges.MaxRows
End Sub
```

Comment: this was perfect, I eventually found it this Form_Load and was able to compare what you described above to solve what I needed. Thank you